# Memory leak using CGAL's exact kernel

Tags: memory-leaks, cgal

I am working on a project that uses OpenMP and the exact kernel of CGAL. As I was running my code in debug mode, and thanks to Visual Studio Leak Detector, I discovered a lot of unexpected memory leaks that are obviously related to the combination of those features. I know that an instance of `CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>` a.k.a. `FT` should not be shared between multiple threads, but since it is not the case here, I thought it was safe. Is there any way to fix these leaks ?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
int main()
{
   double xs_h = 1.2;

#pragma omp parallel
   {
      FT xs;
      std::stringstream stream;
      stream << xs_h;
      stream >> xs;
   }
}
```

And here is (part of) the output of VLD (7 memory leaks in total, all pointing to the same line of code):

```
---------- Block 26 at 0x00000000FEED2E50: 40 bytes ----------
Leak Hash: 0x6B0C3782, Count: 1, Total 40 bytes
Call Stack (TID 15080):
ucrtbased.dll!malloc()
D:\agent\_work\9\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\heap\new_scalar.cpp (35): Test.exe!operator new() + 0xA bytes
D:\CGAL-4.13\include\CGAL\Lazy.h (818): Test.exe!CGAL::Lazy<CGAL::Interval_nt<0>,CGAL::Gmpq,CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>,CGAL::To_interval<CGAL::Gmpq> >::zero() + 0x77 bytes
D:\CGAL-4.13\include\CGAL\Lazy.h (766): Test.exe!CGAL::Lazy<CGAL::Interval_nt<0>,CGAL::Gmpq,CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>,CGAL::To_interval<CGAL::Gmpq> >::Lazy<CGAL::Interval_nt<0>,CGAL::Gmpq,CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>,CGAL::To_interval<CGAL::Gmpq> >() + 0x5 bytes
D:\CGAL-4.13\include\CGAL\Lazy_exact_nt.h (365): Test.exe!CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>() + 0x28 bytes
D:\projects\...\src\main.cpp (20): Test.exe!main$omp$1() + 0xA bytes
VCOMP140D.DLL!vcomp_fork() + 0x2E5 bytes
VCOMP140D.DLL!vcomp_fork() + 0x2A1 bytes
VCOMP140D.DLL!vcomp_atomic_div_r8() + 0x20A bytes
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk() + 0x14 bytes
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() + 0x21 bytes
```

I am using CGAL 4.13, and my compiler is Visual Studio 2019. I tried recompiling this code with macro CGAL_HAS_THREADS but it does not change the result (memory leaks do not vanish). Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You should try [this patch](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/5402) that fixes the thread safety issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in concrete terms, what should I do ? I already tried to run this piece of code with and without ```CGAL_HAS_THREADS``` and it leaks in both cases. Should I download a more recent version of CGAL than 4.13 ?

Comment: zero() is not a real leak, it remains accessible. It is done on purpose to avoid creating millions of equivalent objects. Bad leaks are the ones that repeat the longer a program runs, that's not the case here. Your 7 "leaks" probably all have different template parameters by the way (or maybe there is 1 per thread, but you don't have threads in your program).

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/thread-local/798234 could be relevant, destruction of thread_local objects has always been problematic. If you use the branch linked by sloriot, you can try replacing the code in zero() with `static Self z(new Lazy_rep_0<AT, ET, E2A>());`, although that could cause more contention. Or make it `return new Lazy_rep_0<AT, ET, E2A>();` if you don't like sharing and don't mind the unnecessary constructions.